# Ms deploy publish unneeded files like designer files

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, msdeploy

I am using ms deploy for publishing my web application by command line,

I have use following command

```
<Exec Command="msdeploy -verb:sync 
    -source:contentPath='D:\Impetus\Parmeshthee\Cruise_Control_Setup_Parmeshthee\SVNProjects\QATV2\QAT\' 
    -dest:contentPath='D:\Impetus\Parmeshthee\Cruise_Control_Setup_Parmeshthee\Projects_Publish\QATDemo'" 
    ContinueOnError="false" 
    WorkingDirectory="C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2"
/>
```

But it is just copying all the files and folder from source dir.

I don't want to send designer.cs pages to publish folder.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think msdeploy.exe does the building for, just the deployment.

My best guess is that you can create a package first, and then use the msdeploy to deploy the package. 
http://forums.iis.net/t/1171736.aspx

Or somehow compile on your machine so the output is just .aspx files and binaries and then use msdeploy